# Ember 2, acceptance testing, websocket pending hangs andThen() wating for pending to finish

Tags: sockets, ember.js, websocket, ember-cli, acceptance-testing

I'm starting for the first time in Acceptance testing my Ember application.

So I started from **login** with this:

*test/acceptance/login-test.js*:

```
import { test } from "qunit";
import moduleForAcceptance from "myapp/tests/helpers/module-for-acceptance";

moduleForAcceptance("Acceptance | login");

test("Should login", function(assert) {
  visit("/login");
  fillIn("input[type=email]", "user@email.com");
  fillIn("input[type=password]", "userpass");
  click("button[type=submit]");

  andThen(() => {
    assert.equal(currentURL(), "/");
    assert.equal(find("h1").text(), "Hello!");
  });
});
```

It **never goes** in `andThen()`, so it hangs on `click("button[type=submit]");`.

I understand why.

In my *app/templates/index.hbs* I have a component **notifications** which rely on a websocket which is constantly in pending in my single page application (if I open Chrome there is a pending websocket call...).

If I remove this component from my *index.hbs* everything works as expected.

After the login I should tell to `andThen()` helper to ignore the pending state of that `service('notifications')` which is constantly in pending state?

**How to do?**

Answer (score 1):

For me I was facing this because of one polling method I used which was calling my server in few seconds to fetch something. What I did was disable that code when running in test mode

```
if(!Ember.testing){
  //polling
}
```

AndThen() basically waits for all your promises to resolved before it executes.

Comment: It should be `Ember.testing`, not `Ember.test`.